# Devcontainer build error when using podman with vscode

Tags: docker, podman, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

Here is the complete log of the problem.
After processing all the features, it seems to jump into error while copying files (no such file or directory found) and ultimately fails.

But when I actually checked the path, it did have files.

`.devcontainer.json` is below the logs.

```
[2023-07-21T14:46:38.324Z] Dev Containers 0.299.0 in VS Code 1.80.1 (74f6148eb9ea00507ec113ec51c489d6ffb4b771).
[2023-07-21T14:46:38.324Z] Start: Resolving Remote
[2023-07-21T14:46:38.338Z] Setting up container for folder or workspace: c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot
[2023-07-21T14:46:38.339Z] Start: Run: wsl -l -v
[2023-07-21T14:46:38.418Z] Stop (79 ms): Run: wsl -l -v
[2023-07-21T14:46:38.419Z] Start: Run: wsl -d Ubuntu -e /bin/sh -c echo ~
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.086Z] Stop (1667 ms): Run: wsl -d Ubuntu -e /bin/sh -c echo ~
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.087Z] Start: Run: wsl -d Ubuntu -e /bin/sh -c cd '/home/mrdgh2821' && /bin/sh
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.090Z] Start: Run in host: id -un
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.141Z] mrdgh2821
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.141Z] 
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.141Z] Stop (51 ms): Run in host: id -un
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.141Z] Start: Run in host: cat /etc/passwd
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.142Z] Stop (1 ms): Run in host: cat /etc/passwd
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.142Z] Start: Run in host: echo ~
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.142Z] /home/mrdgh2821
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.143Z] 
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.143Z] Stop (1 ms): Run in host: echo ~
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.143Z] Start: Run in host: test -x '/home/mrdgh2821/.vscode-remote-containers/bin/74f6148eb9ea00507ec113ec51c489d6ffb4b771/node'
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.144Z] 
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.144Z] 
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.144Z] Stop (1 ms): Run in host: test -x '/home/mrdgh2821/.vscode-remote-containers/bin/74f6148eb9ea00507ec113ec51c489d6ffb4b771/node'
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.144Z] Start: Run in host: test -f '/home/mrdgh2821/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/vscode-remote-containers-server-0.299.0.js'
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.145Z] 
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.145Z] 
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.145Z] Stop (1 ms): Run in host: test -f '/home/mrdgh2821/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/vscode-remote-containers-server-0.299.0.js'
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.146Z] userEnvProbe: loginInteractiveShell (default)
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.146Z] userEnvProbe: not found in cache
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.146Z] userEnvProbe shell: /bin/bash
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.238Z] userEnvProbe PATHs:
Probe:     '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/GnuPG/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/RedHat/Podman/:/mnt/c/Users/mihir/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/mihir/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/:/mnt/c/Users/mihir/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/mihir/AppData/Local/Programs/oh-my-posh/bin:/mnt/c/Users/mihir/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/mihir/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/bin:/mnt/c/Users/mihir/AppData/Local/gitkraken/bin:/mnt/c/Users/mihir/bin:/mnt/c/Users/mihir/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/cli-bin:/mnt/c/Users/mihir/AppData/Roaming/sh.loft.devpod/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/RedHat/Podman:/snap/bin'
Container: None
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.239Z] Start: Check Docker is running
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.240Z] Start: Run: podman version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}}
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.506Z] Stop (266 ms): Run: podman version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}}
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.506Z] Server API version: 4.5.0
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.506Z] Stop (267 ms): Check Docker is running
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.506Z] Start: Run: podman volume ls -q
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.758Z] Stop (252 ms): Run: podman volume ls -q
[2023-07-21T14:46:40.758Z] Start: Run: podman volume create vscode
[2023-07-21T14:46:41.010Z] Stop (252 ms): Run: podman volume create vscode
[2023-07-21T14:46:41.010Z] Start: Run: podman ps -q -a --filter label=vsch.local.folder=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot --filter label=vsch.quality=stable
[2023-07-21T14:46:41.267Z] Stop (257 ms): Run: podman ps -q -a --filter label=vsch.local.folder=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot --filter label=vsch.quality=stable
[2023-07-21T14:46:41.268Z] Start: Run: podman ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json
[2023-07-21T14:46:41.498Z] Stop (230 ms): Run: podman ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json
[2023-07-21T14:46:41.498Z] Start: Run: podman ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot
[2023-07-21T14:46:41.747Z] Stop (249 ms): Run: podman ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot
[2023-07-21T14:46:41.747Z] Start: Run: podman ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot
[2023-07-21T14:46:42.007Z] Stop (260 ms): Run: podman ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot
[2023-07-21T14:46:42.008Z] Start: Run: C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node c:\Users\mihir\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js read-configuration --docker-path podman --workspace-folder c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot --id-label devcontainer.config_file=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --mount-workspace-git-root true
[2023-07-21T14:46:42.273Z] @devcontainers/cli 0.46.0. Node.js v16.17.1. win32 10.0.22621 x64.
[2023-07-21T14:46:42.273Z] Start: Run: git rev-parse --show-cdup
[2023-07-21T14:46:42.313Z] Stop (40 ms): Run: git rev-parse --show-cdup
[2023-07-21T14:46:42.313Z] Start: Run: podman ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json
[2023-07-21T14:46:42.548Z] Stop (235 ms): Run: podman ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json
[2023-07-21T14:46:42.552Z] Stop (544 ms): Run: C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node c:\Users\mihir\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js read-configuration --docker-path podman --workspace-folder c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot --id-label devcontainer.config_file=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --mount-workspace-git-root true
[2023-07-21T14:46:42.553Z] Start: Run: C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node c:\Users\mihir\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder c:\Users\mihir\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data --docker-path podman --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-170407c1-7720-483b-8734-551fc3ab2fb41689950797831 --workspace-folder c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot --id-label devcontainer.config_file=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
[2023-07-21T14:46:42.711Z] @devcontainers/cli 0.46.0. Node.js v16.17.1. win32 10.0.22621 x64.
[2023-07-21T14:46:42.711Z] Start: Run: podman buildx version
[2023-07-21T14:46:42.907Z] Stop (196 ms): Run: podman buildx version
[2023-07-21T14:46:42.908Z] buildah 1.31.0
[2023-07-21T14:46:42.908Z] 
[2023-07-21T14:46:42.908Z] Start: Resolving Remote
[2023-07-21T14:46:42.910Z] Start: Run: git rev-parse --show-cdup
[2023-07-21T14:46:42.935Z] Stop (25 ms): Run: git rev-parse --show-cdup
[2023-07-21T14:46:43.229Z] Start: Run: podman ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json
[2023-07-21T14:46:43.458Z] Stop (229 ms): Run: podman ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json
[2023-07-21T14:46:43.458Z] Start: Run: podman inspect --type image mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/typescript-node:18
[2023-07-21T14:46:43.710Z] Stop (252 ms): Run: podman inspect --type image mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/typescript-node:18
[2023-07-21T14:46:43.711Z] local container features stored at: c:\Users\mihir\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0\dist\node_modules\vscode-dev-containers\container-features
[2023-07-21T14:46:43.711Z] Start: Run: tar --no-same-owner -x -f -
[2023-07-21T14:46:43.737Z] Stop (26 ms): Run: tar --no-same-owner -x -f -
[2023-07-21T14:46:43.747Z] Resolving Feature dependencies for 'ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/typescript:2'...
[2023-07-21T14:46:43.747Z] * Processing feature: ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/typescript:2
[2023-07-21T14:46:44.220Z] Start: Run: docker-credential-wincred get
[2023-07-21T14:46:44.226Z] findLocalWindowsExecutable: Exectuable 'docker-credential-wincred' not found on PATH 'C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Gpg4win\..\GnuPG\bin;C:\Program Files\RedHat\Podman\;C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\;C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\bin;C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Local\gitkraken\bin;C:\Users\mihir\bin;;c:\Users\mihir\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\cli-bin;C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Roaming\sh.loft.devpod\bin;C:\Program Files\RedHat\Podman'.
[2023-07-21T14:46:46.225Z] * Processing feature: ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/npm-package
[2023-07-21T14:46:47.829Z] Resolving Feature dependencies for 'ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/desktop-lite:1'...
[2023-07-21T14:46:47.829Z] * Processing feature: ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/desktop-lite:1
[2023-07-21T14:46:49.324Z] * Processing feature: ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/common-utils
[2023-07-21T14:46:52.353Z] Resolving Feature dependencies for 'ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/git:1'...
[2023-07-21T14:46:52.353Z] * Processing feature: ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/git:1
[2023-07-21T14:46:53.881Z] * Processing feature: ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/common-utils
[2023-07-21T14:46:55.738Z] Resolving Feature dependencies for 'ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/node:1'...
[2023-07-21T14:46:55.738Z] * Processing feature: ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/node:1
[2023-07-21T14:46:57.372Z] * Processing feature: ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/common-utils
[2023-07-21T14:46:59.571Z] Resolving Feature dependencies for 'ghcr.io/dhoeric/features/hadolint:1'...
[2023-07-21T14:46:59.571Z] * Processing feature: ghcr.io/dhoeric/features/hadolint:1
[2023-07-21T14:47:01.055Z] * Processing feature: ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/common-utils
[2023-07-21T14:47:02.773Z] Soft-dependency 'ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/npm-package' is not required.  Removing from installation order...
[2023-07-21T14:47:02.773Z] Soft-dependency 'ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/common-utils' is not required.  Removing from installation order...
[2023-07-21T14:47:02.773Z] Soft-dependency 'ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/common-utils' is not required.  Removing from installation order...
[2023-07-21T14:47:02.773Z] Soft-dependency 'ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/common-utils' is not required.  Removing from installation order...
[2023-07-21T14:47:02.773Z] Soft-dependency 'ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/common-utils' is not required.  Removing from installation order...
[2023-07-21T14:47:02.773Z] * Fetching feature: typescript_0_oci
[2023-07-21T14:47:03.613Z] * Fetching feature: desktop-lite_1_oci
[2023-07-21T14:47:04.724Z] * Fetching feature: git_2_oci
[2023-07-21T14:47:05.626Z] * Fetching feature: node_3_oci
[2023-07-21T14:47:06.567Z] * Fetching feature: hadolint_4_oci
[2023-07-21T14:47:07.398Z] Start: Run: podman buildx build --load --build-context dev_containers_feature_content_source=C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Local\Temp\devcontainercli\container-features\0.46.0-1689950803711 --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_BASE_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/typescript-node:18 --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_IMAGE_USER=root --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_FEATURE_CONTENT_SOURCE=dev_container_feature_content_temp --target dev_containers_target_stage -t vsc-discord-ban-utils-bot-1aa5cea51a6a29accd4e5bf90982d33d7326a6face5746c5a4de512e457efaa4-features -f C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Local\Temp\devcontainercli\container-features\0.46.0-1689950803711\Dockerfile.extended c:\Users\mihir\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data\empty-folder
[2023-07-21T14:47:07.489Z] 
[2023-07-21T14:47:07.658Z] time="2023-07-21T20:17:07+05:30" level=error msg="While reading directory C:\\Us
ers\\mihir\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\ms-vscode-remote.remote
-containers\\data\\empty-folder: EOF"
[2023-07-21T14:47:07.750Z] [1/2] STEP 1/4: FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/typescript-node:18 AS dev_c
ontainers_feature_content_normalize
[2023-07-21T14:47:07.780Z] [1/2] STEP 2/4: USER root
[2023-07-21T14:47:07.842Z] --> bfc01760b30c
[1/2] STEP 3/4: COPY --from=dev_containers_feature_content_source devcontainer-f
eatures.builtin.env /tmp/build-features/
[2023-07-21T14:47:07.871Z] Error: building at STEP "COPY --from=dev_containers_feature_content_source devco
ntainer-features.builtin.env /tmp/build-features/": checking on sources under "/
C:\\Users\\mihir\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\devcontainercli\\container-features\\0.4
6.0-1689950803711": error in copier subprocess: changing to intended-new-root di
rectory "/C:\\Users\\mihir\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\devcontainercli\\container-fea
tures\\0.46.0-1689950803711": chdir /C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Local\Temp\devcontai
nercli\container-features\0.46.0-1689950803711: no such file or directory

[2023-07-21T14:47:07.932Z] Stop (534 ms): Run: podman buildx build --load --build-context dev_containers_feature_content_source=C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Local\Temp\devcontainercli\container-features\0.46.0-1689950803711 --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_BASE_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/typescript-node:18 --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_IMAGE_USER=root --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_FEATURE_CONTENT_SOURCE=dev_container_feature_content_temp --target dev_containers_target_stage -t vsc-discord-ban-utils-bot-1aa5cea51a6a29accd4e5bf90982d33d7326a6face5746c5a4de512e457efaa4-features -f C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Local\Temp\devcontainercli\container-features\0.46.0-1689950803711\Dockerfile.extended c:\Users\mihir\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data\empty-folder
[2023-07-21T14:47:07.932Z] Error: Command failed: podman buildx build --load --build-context dev_containers_feature_content_source=C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Local\Temp\devcontainercli\container-features\0.46.0-1689950803711 --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_BASE_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/typescript-node:18 --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_IMAGE_USER=root --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_FEATURE_CONTENT_SOURCE=dev_container_feature_content_temp --target dev_containers_target_stage -t vsc-discord-ban-utils-bot-1aa5cea51a6a29accd4e5bf90982d33d7326a6face5746c5a4de512e457efaa4-features -f C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Local\Temp\devcontainercli\container-features\0.46.0-1689950803711\Dockerfile.extended c:\Users\mihir\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data\empty-folder
[2023-07-21T14:47:07.932Z]     at Mte (c:\Users\mihir\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:2007:1066)
[2023-07-21T14:47:07.932Z]     at n3 (c:\Users\mihir\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:2007:1002)
[2023-07-21T14:47:07.933Z]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[2023-07-21T14:47:07.933Z]     at async rre (c:\Users\mihir\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:2024:3660)
[2023-07-21T14:47:07.933Z]     at async Yf (c:\Users\mihir\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:2024:4775)
[2023-07-21T14:47:07.933Z]     at async Dne (c:\Users\mihir\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:2156:12193)
[2023-07-21T14:47:07.933Z]     at async Sne (c:\Users\mihir\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:2156:11934)
[2023-07-21T14:47:07.938Z] Stop (25385 ms): Run: C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node c:\Users\mihir\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder c:\Users\mihir\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data --docker-path podman --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-170407c1-7720-483b-8734-551fc3ab2fb41689950797831 --workspace-folder c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot --id-label devcontainer.config_file=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
[2023-07-21T14:47:07.938Z] Exit code 1
[2023-07-21T14:47:07.940Z] Command failed: C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node c:\Users\mihir\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder c:\Users\mihir\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data --docker-path podman --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-170407c1-7720-483b-8734-551fc3ab2fb41689950797831 --workspace-folder c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot --id-label devcontainer.config_file=c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config c:\Users\mihir\GitHub\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
[2023-07-21T14:47:07.940Z] Exit code 1
```

Here is `.devcontainer.json`

```json
{
  "name": "Node.js & TypeScript",
  "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/typescript-node:18",
  "postCreateCommand": "bash .devcontainer/setup.sh",
  "features": {
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/typescript:2": {},
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/desktop-lite:1": {},
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/git:1": {},
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/node:1": {},
    "ghcr.io/dhoeric/features/hadolint:1": {}
  },
  "customizations": {
    "vscode": {
      "extensions": [
        "christian-kohler.npm-intellisense",
        "christian-kohler.path-intellisense",
        "cschlosser.doxdocgen",
        "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
        "eamodio.gitlens",
        "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "exiasr.hadolint",
        "MichaelCurrin.auto-commit-msg",
        "p42ai.refactor",
        "Phu1237.vs-browser",
        "redhat.vscode-yaml",
        "spmeesseman.vscode-taskexplorer",
        "streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker",
        "usernamehw.errorlens"
      ]
    }
  },
  "forwardPorts": [
    5901,
    6080
  ],
  "remoteUser": "vscode",
  "runArgs": [
    "--userns=keep-id"
  ],
  "containerUser": "vscode",
  "updateRemoteUserUID": true,
  "containerEnv": {
    "HOME": "/home/vscode"
  },
  "workspaceMount": "source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/workspace,type=bind,Z",
  "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
}
```

I saw multiple websites & github issues and added following lines to the `devcontainer.json`

```json
"remoteUser": "vscode",
  "runArgs": [
    "--userns=keep-id"
  ],
  "containerUser": "vscode",
  "updateRemoteUserUID": true,
  "containerEnv": {
    "HOME": "/home/vscode"
  },
  "workspaceMount": "source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/workspace,type=bind,Z",
  "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
```

Still it didn't work as expected, with same error coming again.

Podman 4.5.1 had same error, Podman 4.6.0 also had same error.

I'm on Windows 11, so some of the linux solutions didn't work for me.